# $f(n) = 2f(n/2) + n^2$ if n is even or $2f(n/2) + n^3$ if n is odd

Tags: asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I want to solve the following recursion to find the complexity.

$f(n)=\begin{cases}
               2f(n/2) + n^2 & \textbf{if } n \text{ is even}\\
               2f(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + n^3 & \textbf{if } n \text{ is odd}
            \end{cases}
$

It is clear that

- if $n=2^k$ (10000...000) for some $k>1$ the answer is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$
- if $n=2^k-1$ for some $k>1$ the answer is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$

The bits of the $n$ determines the complexity.

So exactly when it is  $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ or  $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$